# SQ-Lite doesn't show as data provider in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I currently reinstalled **Windows 7** and in the process decided to upgrade from Visual Studio 2010 to VS 2015. I was working on a project (in C# / WPF ) using SQ-Lite and now I can't get SQ-Lite to run with VS 2015, specifically **VS2015 doesn't recognize SQ-Lite as a data provider.**

I have taken the following steps:

1. Installed sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.98.0.exe from the website http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
2. In VS (successfully) installed the NuGet-Packages System.Data.SQLite.EF6 and System.Data.SQLite via the Package-Console
3. In my app.config I have added this line in DBProviderFactories:

   ```
   <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
   ```
4. I have removed and re-added the references, built/rebuilt the project, restarted VS2015, restarted Windows etc.
5. I checked if the respective .dll files are allowed to be copied locally. ( The .dll for System.Data.SQLite.EF6 isn't in the project directory, but is referenced, I don't know if that is relevant)

Additionally, i have no admin rights on the system I'm working with, but the installations of VS 2015 and SQ-Lite (see step 1) were done by an admin, the NuGet packages I installed myself.

Obviously I am missing something and I'd appreciate any input. How can I get VS 2015 to identify SQ-Lite as a data provider?

Answer (score 3):

Try to install:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.98.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.98.0.exe

This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2015.

It's worked for me  in VS 2015 Community ..

Comment: Thanks, worked very well, VS 2015 finally recogizes SQ-Lite as a data provider, unfortunately now the compiler shows me errors "Error No. CS0234 and CS0246", because it's missing the System.Data namespaces. Any ideas?